# SQL : create database by concatenating machine name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have to create a query which should create a database by concatenating the machine name and any given name. I have following SQL query but I am getting an error. Please suggest me.

```
DECLARE @machinename VARCHAR(100)    
SET @machinename=HOST_NAME()   

CREATE DATABASE @machinename+' Test'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Dynamic SQL and you need to remove the space in the `' Test'` portion:

```
DECLARE @machinename VARCHAR(100)    
declare @sql varchar(max)
SET @machinename=HOST_NAME()  
set @sql = 'CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@machinename + '_Test')

execute(@sql)
```

From [MSDN Database identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx):

> Embedded spaces or special characters are not allowed.

Comment: +1 for the "Embedded spaces or special characters are not allowed." warning

Comment: well i guess space is not creating any problem..it is working fine.

Comment: "Not allowed" is incorrect. That should probably say "not recommended."

Comment: @AaronBertrand that is directly taken from MSDN. So I guess their documentation is wrong.

Comment: @bluefeet understood, I was suggesting the documentation was incorrect, not your copying of it. :-)

Comment: Embedded spaces *are* allowed if the identifier is brace-style. Any character at all is possible including braces.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know why would you want to do this, but you are gonna need dynamic SQL (so first, go to [this link](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)). That said, you can do:

```
DECLARE @machinename VARCHAR(100), @SQL VARCHAR(8000)
SET @machinename=HOST_NAME()
SET @SQL = 'CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@machinename + ' Test')
EXEC(@SQL)
```